# Dungeons and Dragons novel where girl accidentally wishes to be strong

Tags: story-identification, episode-identification, dungeons-and-dragons

Does any one know the name of the novel, written before 1995, from one of the *Dungeons and Dragons* series, where a girl accidentally wishes to become strong at the start of the novel? I remember that the protagonist is surprised and dismayed to have become strong. I can't remember which realm this was in.

Comment: I think this is a Forgotten Realms story, I recall a sorceress doing this and being dismayed at the outcome.  I just need to find the story.....

Comment: Linked duplicate question was accepted in comments.

Comment: @user118472: It's not a bad thing that your question got marked as a duplicate. It's just part of our bookkeeping.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This could be [Pool of Radiance](https://forgottenrealms.fandom.com/wiki/Pool_of_Radiance_(novel)), a Forgotten Realms story based on, iirc, an early computer game.  The book was first published in [1989](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pool_of_Radiance).

Shal Bal is the apprentice to a powerful, kindly master who is killed, and she inherits his belongings, one of which is a Ring of Wishes

> When Shal Bal of Cormyr's master, Ranthor, receives a message from his old friend and fellow mage, Denlor of Phlan, whose tower is under siege by hundreds of monsters, Ranthor rushes to aid him. Shortly, Shal receives a message from Ranthor via crystal ball, during which he warns 'beware the dragon of bronze'[2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pool_of_Radiance) and is murdered by an unknown assailant. Shal inherits Ranthor's familiar, a white horse named Cerulean, and Ranthor's various magical items, including a staff of power and a ring of three wishes. However, along the way to the Moonsea, when she wishes she were able to lift a large pack, she is turned into a hulking, seven-foot-tall giant by the ring. In her rage, she wishes she were at Phlan, and is teleported there instantly.

Comment: I remember being amused at how quickly we wound up with three Amazonian females, all working together, and how it took me years to realize this was probably accounting for a particular author fetish.